# How to change the UI state of a group of Checkboxes with Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, formik

I have a series of checkboxes that need to change their UI when they are clicked. For example, if the first checkbox is clicked, it should change color independently from the others.

This is my current work, but it works like a radio button because only one checkbox is checked at a time.

```js
function RecordGame() {
const [checkedStatus, setCheckedStatus] = useState(members.map(() => false))

  const handleSetChecked = async (index) => {
    let newState = members.map(() => false)
    console.log(newState)
    newState[index] = true
    setCheckedStatus(newState)
  }

  
const playerCheckboxes = members.map((player, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="flex gap-2">
      <label htmlFor={player.name}>
        <Field
          checked
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={() => handleSetChecked(index)}
          id={player.name}
          name="players"
          value={player.name}
        />
        <span
          // Change the checkbox UI based on the checkedStatus
          className={`${checkedStatus[index] ? 'bg-quad text-primary' : 'bg-transparent'}`}
        >
          {player.name}
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
})

return( {playerCheckboxes} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `handleSetChecked` is called, this below code line always resets the `checkedStatus` to `unchecked` for all items in the array.

```
let newState = members.map(() => false)
```

Than this line `newState[index] = true` in the same function causing the checkbox to behave as `radio` button, since for a particular index, it is always setting the status as `checked`.

To fix the issue, you need to update `handleSetChecked` function, such that it should not reset the `checkedStatus` and take care of the previous value for the same index to handle the check and uncheck state for the checkbox.

```
const handleSetChecked = async (index) => {
  let newState = [...checkedStatus] // make a copy of the current state of the checkedStatus
  newState[index] = !checkedStatus[index] // update the relevant index based on the previous state. If its checked, uncheck it and vice versa.
  setCheckedStatus(newState)
}
```